# Is it possible to convert an XML string into JSON in ColdFusion Fusion 8

Tags: xml, json, coldfusion-8

I'm in a situation, where i receive a query containing XML string. I'm supposed to convert it to json.

I wrote a small CF Function, that traverses/parse through the XML and conveniently transforms it into a json. Now the problem is, the XML schema has been changed, which is forcing me to re-write the CF function to suit the new schema.

Is there a more better/generic way of converting XML into json? (using ColdFusion though!)

Answer (score 6):

There is [XSLTJSON](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/).

Download the XSLT stylesheet and use it with ColdFusion's [`XmlTransform()` function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e8e.html).

```
<cfset xmlDoc  = XmlParse(yourXmlString, true)>

<cfset params  = StructNew()>
<cfset params["any-param"] = "you wish to pass to the XSL processor">

<cfset jsonStr = XmlTransform(xmlDoc, "xml-to-json.xsl", params)>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm currently using cold fusion 8, I'm getting following error (I've used the XSLT v2.0)  :(

Comment: `javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: "as" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:param element!
A Transformer object cannot be created that satisfies the configuration requested. This could be due to a failure in compiling the XSL text. javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: "as" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:param element! `

Comment: @novein: Oh, it seems that the XSLT is version 2.0, and ColdFusion (natively) only supports XSLT 1.0. I must admit that I hadn't checked for that. :-\ Sorry.

Comment: @novein: http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/ has an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet you can try.

Comment: The function is actually called `XMLTransform` not `XSLTransform`.

Comment: @Seybsen Whoops, you're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing this out! (It was correct in the text, and wrong in the code. D'oh.)

Answer (score 1):

Got this working today, had to import the current Saxon libs and write a small java helper file.

```
public static String transformXML(String xmlData, String xslFile) throws SaxonApiException 
{

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XdmNode source = null;

    Processor proc = new Processor(false);
    XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();
    XsltExecutable exp = comp.compile(new StreamSource(new File(xslFile)));

    try
    {
        source = proc.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Serializer out = proc.newSerializer(sw);
    //out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "html");
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
    XsltTransformer trans = exp.load();
    trans.setInitialContextNode(source);
    trans.setDestination(out);
    trans.transform();

    return sw.toString();
}
```